# Why is there an error “invalid data input” when I try to test a successfully deployed ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I followed a sample notebook to create a IBM cloud machine learning model using `scikit-learn`. The tutorial [can be found here](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/168e65a9e8d2e6174a4e2e2765aa4df1).

Every cell runs correctly and the model is deployed successfully, but when I click into the model and try to make a prediction, an error “Invalid input data” shows up. Why does this issue occur and how should I solve this?

[image]

```
wml_credentials = {
  "username": "****",
  "password": "****",
  "instance_id": "****",
  "url": "https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net”
}
```

When creating the API client, I tried changing the `url` from `"https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net”` to `"https://us-south.ml.cloud.ibm.com”`.

I also tried adding the access key like:

```
wml_credentials = {
  "access_key”: "****",
  "username": "****",
  "password": "****",
  "instance_id": "****",
  "url": "https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net”
}
```

Nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing individual values for f0,f1,f2..... You can pass the input as JSON shown below

```
{
  "fields" : [ "f0", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "f10", "f11", "f12", "f13", "f14", "f15", "f16", "f17", "f18", "f19", "f20", "f21", "f22", "f23", "f24", "f25", "f26", "f27", "f28", "f29", "f30", "f31", "f32", "f33", "f34", "f35", "f36", "f37", "f38", "f39", "f40", "f41", "f42", "f43", "f44", "f45", "f46", "f47", "f48", "f49", "f50", "f51", "f52", "f53", "f54", "f55", "f56", "f57", "f58", "f59", "f60", "f61", "f62", "f63" ],
  "values" : [ [ 0.0, 5.0, 12.0, 13.0, 16.0, 16.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11.0, 16.0, 15.0, 8.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 14.0, 11.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 16.0, 16.0, 14.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 6.0, 6.0, 16.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 16.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 5.0, 15.0, 13.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 15.0, 16.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] ]
}
```

Attaching is a screenshot on how to pass JSON input under deployment

[image]

I just verified the notebook and you don't have to change the ML URL.